# Drawing with glDrawArray

Tags: ios, opengl-es, cocos2d-iphone

In my `draw` function within my `CCLayer`. I'm drawing some lines and `CGPoints` are stored in `std::vector`. I've successfully drew the lines using ccDrawLine. However, when using `glDrawArray`, nothing shows up. I've included screenshots of the results. As you can see when using ccDrawnLine it drew the lines correctly. Any ideas?

[Update] I'm using Cocos2d v2.0 and by default it uses OpenGLES 2.0.

```
//openGLES
#include <OpenGLES/EAGL.h>
#include <OpenGLES/ES2/gl.h>
#include <OpenGLES/ES2/glext.h>

- (void) draw {
    glLineWidth( 3.0f );

    //begin and clear
    [renderTexture beginWithClear:waveform4F.r g:waveform4F.g b:waveform4F.b a:waveform4F.a];
    vector<CGPoint> vertices = bufferQueue.front();

    if (WaveformStyleLined) {
        for (int i = 1; i < vertices.size(); i++)
            ccDrawLine(vertices[i - 1], vertices[i]);
    } else {
        ccGLEnableVertexAttribs( kCCVertexAttribFlag_Position );
        kmGLPushMatrix();

        glVertexAttribPointer(kCCVertexAttrib_Position, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(CGPoint), &vertices[0]);
        glDrawArrays(GL_LINES, sizeof(CGPoint), vertices.size());

        kmGLPopMatrix();
    }

    bufferQueue.pop();
    [renderTexture end];
}
```

[image: using ccDrawLine]

[image: using glDrawArrays]

Here are some of my `CGPoint`s in my `vertices`:

```
2012-08-18 08:57:49.750 vertices[1]:NSPoint: {1, 48.09375}
2012-08-18 08:57:49.751 vertices[2]:NSPoint: {2, 47.996094}
2012-08-18 08:57:49.752 vertices[3]:NSPoint: {3, 48.046875}
2012-08-18 08:57:49.753 vertices[4]:NSPoint: {4, 48.214844}
2012-08-18 08:57:49.754 vertices[5]:NSPoint: {5, 48.152344}
2012-08-18 08:57:49.755 vertices[6]:NSPoint: {6, 48.035156}
2012-08-18 08:57:49.755 vertices[7]:NSPoint: {7, 48.078125}
2012-08-18 08:57:49.756 vertices[8]:NSPoint: {8, 48.144531}
2012-08-18 08:57:49.757 vertices[9]:NSPoint: {9, 48.0625}
2012-08-18 08:57:49.757 vertices[10]:NSPoint: {10, 48.242188}
```

Comment: Are you using OpenGL ES 2.0? Did you set a shader?

Comment: I'm using OpenGLES 1.0. No, I didn't set a shader. Do I need to?

Comment: Why are you using GL_TRIANGLES? Shouldn't that be GL_LINES?

Comment: I've shown the first 10 data in my `vertices` variable

Comment: My mistake. Yes, I'm using OpenGLES2.0 since I'm using Cocos2d v2.0. I've updated the question. Thanks DrummerB! I added the shaders and it worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By adding shaders like DrummerB said lines started showing up. I copied the same shader code from Cocos2d and it worked like a charm.

```
//openGLES
#include <OpenGLES/EAGL.h>
#include <OpenGLES/ES2/gl.h>
#include <OpenGLES/ES2/glext.h>

static BOOL initialized = NO;
static CCGLProgram *shader_ = nil;
static int colorLocation_ = -1;
static ccColor4F color_ = {1,1,1,1};
static int pointSizeLocation_ = -1;
static void lazy_init( void )
{
    if( ! initialized ) {

    //
    // Position and 1 color passed as a uniform (to similate glColor4ub )
    //
        shader_ = [[CCShaderCache sharedShaderCache] programForKey:kCCShader_Position_uColor];

        colorLocation_ = glGetUniformLocation( shader_->program_, "u_color");
        pointSizeLocation_ = glGetUniformLocation( shader_->program_, "u_pointSize");

        initialized = YES;
    }
}


- (void) draw {
    glLineWidth( 3.0f );

    //begin and clear
    [renderTexture beginWithClear:waveform4F.r g:waveform4F.g b:waveform4F.b a:waveform4F.a];
    vector<CGPoint> vertices = bufferQueue.front();

    if (WaveformStyleLined) {

        ccDrawPoly(&vertices[0], vertices.size(), false);

    } else {

        lazy_init();

        [shader_ use];
        [shader_ setUniformForModelViewProjectionMatrix];
        [shader_ setUniformLocation:colorLocation_ with4fv:(GLfloat*) &color_.r count:1];

        ccGLEnableVertexAttribs( kCCVertexAttribFlag_Position );

        glVertexAttribPointer(kCCVertexAttrib_Position, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, &vertices[0]);
        glDrawArrays(GL_LINE_STRIP, 0, vertices.size());
    }

    bufferQueue.pop();
    [renderTexture end];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using `ccDrawPoly`, in which internally uses `glDrawArray` and achieve the exact same output as ccDrawLine, but a lot faster since I'm not retrieving point by point. However, I'm still curious on how to do it using pure OpenGL code. Any help or direction will be greatly appreciated.

```
if (WaveformStyleLined) {
    for (int i = 1; i < vertices.size(); i++)
        ccDrawLine(vertices[i - 1], vertices[i]);

} else {
    ccDrawPoly(&vertices[0], vertices.size(), false);
}
```